# Solr 4.3.0 External File Field: despite I followed the official reference, I cannot get it to work

Tags: solr

I have a Solr multicore instance and I'm trying to get advantage from the External File Field feature, but with no success.

Here's the *fieldType* definition

```
<fieldType name="ext_tags" class="solr.ExternalFileField" keyField="doc_id" />
```

Notice the reference guide reports an example with a few more attributes

```
defVal="" stored="false" indexed="false" valType="string"
```

but I guess they're from Solr version 3 because If I add them in my schema.xml, I get an error starting the instance.

Here's the *field* definition

```
<field name="deal_tags" type="ext_tags" indexed="false" stored="true" required="false" />
```

Here's the external data file name ( in $SOLR_HOME/data )

```
external_deal_tags.txt
```

Here's the instance dir ($SOLR_HOME)

```
/opt/solr-4.3.0/deal-ws/cores/it_IT/
```

Here's an excerpt from the data file (UTF-8 encoded, sorted by doc_id that is a MD5 hash)

```
003c9256f23da49233fc0b253f7a93cb=8;12
0050188629a8c0e3f89bcd6a7cb77b3a=6;7;13;33;35;38
009c3932933b173072054e3d81527b05=6
```

Here's the URL I call

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/it_IT/select?q=*:*&wt=json&fl=deal_tags&rows=3&indent=yes
```

Here's the response I get

```
{
   "responseHeader":{
   "status":0,
   "QTime":116},
   "response":{"numFound":3678,"start":0,"docs":[
     {},
     {},
     {}]
}}
```

Even if I change the *rows* param to 4000 (i have 3678 documents in the index) I get no *ext_tags*

After modifying the schema.xml file, I restarted Tomcat many times and I also restarted the hosting machine.

What have I missed?

*** UPDATE ***

During my quest for answers, I found out the problem was possibly in the way I queried Solr. I tried modifying the query using *field()*

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/it_IT/select?q=*:*&wt=json&fl=field(deal_tags)&rows=3&indent=yes
```

and this is what I get now

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2},
    "response":{"numFound":3678,"start":0,"docs":[
      { "field(deal_tags)":0.0},
      { "field(deal_tags)":0.0},
      { "field(deal_tags)":8.0}]
}}
```

I expected to get *strings* instead I get something formatted as a decimal number:
    - first result:   expected 56;57 -> 0.0   
    - second result:  expected blank -> 0.0  (its doc_id is not in the external file)
    - third result:   expected 8     -> 8.0

So, it seems I need to inform Solr I expect this value to be treated as a *string* but I don't get where to set this configuration.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out what was the problem. I took a look in the log file ant here's what I got

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Only float and pfloat (Trie|Float)Field are currently supported as external field type.

So, I cannot use strings as external values.